# What phrase are people saying about 'ה and רחם?‎

Tags: hebrew, speech-talking

I hear a certain phrase a lot.‎ Are people saying ה' ירחם,‎ that השם *should* be merciful,‎ or ה' מרחם,‎ that השם *is* merciful?‎

Thanks!

Comment: How many Google results do you get for each?

Comment: Should be. When talking about something bad happening -- *may G-d have mercy that this not happen anymore!"

Comment: @DoubleAA good point

Comment: @Shalom thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always heard y'racheim. It's just an expression, so I doubt there are any sources available to quote.